# How to get bash command in yii cli action?

Tags: php, bash, yii, command-line-interface

```
class RunCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function actionIndex($site, array $filters = null)
   {
      //here i need the command
   }
}
```

and the invoke(the command which i need in action):

```
php yiic run --site=index --filers=mobiles --filers=tvs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your yiic.php configure path to config file and framework:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yiic.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php';

require_once($yiic);
```

After this you can use `./yiic` or `php yiic.php` to run console commands. Basic command is:

```
class RunCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args)
    {
      //here $args will have your params, just parse them:
      // $args[0] => --site=index, $args[1] => --filers=mobiles etc...
      //here i need the command
    }
}
```

Then just run your command if all ok, `./yiic run --site=index --filers=mobiles --filers=tvs` or `php yiic.php run --site=index --filers=mobiles --filers=tvs`